# How to pass a variable from one Express route to another.?

Tags: node.js, express

Please go ease, I've only started coding a couple of months ago.

How can I access a variable from the placeOrder route in the match route?

```
//Get Price//
const placeOrder = (req, res) => {
var symbol = req.query.symbolID.split(" - ")[0].toUpperCase()
console.log(symbol)
finnhubClient.quote(symbol, (error, data, response) => {
   const currentPrice = data.c
    console.log(currentPrice)
    res.send({ currentPrice })
 });

};
```

I want to pass the currentPrice variable to the this route =>

```
//Match orders 
const match = async(req, res) => {

// I want to access the currentPrice variable here //


const { orderType, orderTimeFrameInput, tradeAmount, symbolSearch, kofTimeInput } = 
 req.body

console.log(req.body.symbolSearch)
const orders = await knex("orderbook_table")
.where({ order_type: "Call" })
.where({ market: symbolSearch })
.select()

console.log(orders)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok you have two main options:

- If your routes come one after the other (for example: /placeorder > /match) you can attach the variable on the request:

```js
// Added 'next' parameter
const placeOrder = (req, res, next) => {
    const symbol = req.query.symbolID.split(" - ")[0].toUpperCase()
    console.log(symbol)
    finnhubClient.quote(symbol, (error, data, response) => {
        const currentPrice = data.c;
        console.log(currentPrice);
        req.currentPrice = currentPrice;
        // By calling next you will navigate to the next route and the request object will have your variable
        next();
    });
};
```

- If your routes are completely separated (which i guess is your case) you can use the local property:

```js
// Don't need to use next anymore, you can evend send a response
const placeOrder = (req, res) => {
    const symbol = req.query.symbolID.split(" - ")[0].toUpperCase()
    console.log(symbol)
    finnhubClient.quote(symbol, (error, data, response) => {
        const currentPrice = data.c;
        console.log(currentPrice);
        // Now all of your routes can access this variable
        req.locals.currentPrice = currentPrice;
        res.send({ currentPrice });
    });
};
```

Be carefull tho, with the second approach your routes will be able to access that variable inside `req.locals.currentPrice` but only after the placeOrder route has been accessed, otherwise it will be undefined.

Hope it helped

EDIT: It's not officially documented but you'll be able to access both `req.locals` and `res.locals`, generally req it's used because if you're using a template renderer(ejs for example) it will use the res.locals and it can cause race conditions

Comment: Hi Nick, thank you very much for your input. Much appreciated. I've decided to go with the second option but I'm getting this error:                         
req.locals.currentPrice = currentPrice;
                                ^

TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'currentPrice')